# Passing username & password into Angular for HTTPS

Tags: angular, http

Im writing some code (trying) to pass a username and password to some IP cameras that use HTTPS.

I have successfully passed a username/password to another type of camera which is HTTP and it displays the web cam feed nicely.

However, when trying to do the same to 10 other IP cameras on HTTPS, I get the broken image display

Can anyone assist? The code with HTTP works, when using HTTPS it fails. I also tried user:pass at in the url.

Thanks!

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="sectionIconContainer"><div class="sectionIcon"><svg viewBox="0 0 48 48"><use xlink:href="/static/matrix-theme/squidink.svg#sun"></use></svg></div></div>
    <div class="title">Cameras</div>
    <div class="controls">

<a href="http://XXXX.ddns.net/bha-api/video.cgi?"><img src ="http://XXXX.ddns.net/bha-api/video.cgi?http-user=XXXX&http-password=XXXX" height="250" width="350"></img></a>

<a href="https://XXXX.ddns.net/cam/"><img src ="https://XXXX.ddns.net/cam/?login=XXXX&password=XXXX!" height="250" width="350"></img></a>
```

Comment: Is there any code that we could see? Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: It sounds like you're using a mix of HTTP and HTTPS. That won't work due to CORS. If you have HTTPS on your website, your images and cameras will all need HTTPS as well. Essentially, you'll need HTTPS throughout.

Comment: Thanks guys. Damn! The camera that uses HTTP doesnt allow HTTPS. Can I somehow proxy this with nginx so that the HTTP url is referencing used HTTPS?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you use HTTPS resources in your web app. You need to host the web app itself on HTTPS as well.

Comment: OK, lets assume I remove the HTTP URL, they are then all HTTPs. What would I need in terms of url to pass though details over?